# Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init() not found

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I'm trying to get [Oxyplot](http://www.oxyplot.org/) to run with Xamarin for an Android app. The documentation states the following:

> **Initialize renderers**
>
> You need to initialize the OxyPlot renderers by adding the following
>   call just after Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init():
>
> ```
> iOS (Unified API): OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
> Android: OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
> Universal Windows: OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
> Windows Phone: OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WP8.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
> ```
>
> Tip: Search for “Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init()” in your solution to find
>   all the places you need to add code.

I searched for "Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init()" in my solution but this string is nowhere to be found. Any hints on how to proceed from here and how to get a simple oxyplot sample application to run?

Comment: in Android this called in "protected override void OnCreate" in MainActivity.cs

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init()` is called in `protected override void OnCreate` in `MainActivity.cs`.

```
[Activity(Label = "fooApp", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```